# Calculation of lexicographic permutations

Tags: combinatorics, common-lisp

Just for fun, I studied the generation of [lexicographic permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order) and came across the following [algorithm](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/AllPerm.shtml) which I *transcribed* into Common Lisp, as good as I can, being a hobbyist:

```
(defun lexicographic-permutation% (order n)
  "Returns the Nth permutation of integers from 0 upto order."
  (let* ((range (loop :for i :upto order :collect i))
         (len (1+ order))
         (permutation (make-array len :initial-contents range)))
    (loop :while (< count n)
          :for count :from 1
          :for i = order
          :for j = len
          :do
          (loop :while (>= (aref permutation (1- i))
                           (aref permutation i))
                    :do (decf i))
          (loop :while (<= (aref permutation (1- j))
                           (aref permutation (1- i)))
                :do (decf j))
          (rotatef (aref permutation (1- i))
                   (aref permutation (1- j)))
          (incf i)
          (setf j len)
          (loop :while (< i j)
                :do (rotatef (aref permutation (1- i))
                             (aref permutation (1- j)))
                    (incf i)
                    (decf j))
          :finally (return permutation))))
```

While it is working and fast I am unsure about the explicit side-effects using `setf` and `incf` and the structure of the loops. I know that Common Lisp is not a strict functional language and allows several paradigmas which is considered to be an advantage. But I was asking myself if the algorithm could be written in a clearer idiom in CL.

I was thinking about packing the `rotatef`-pattern in an extra function which could be inlined. But this is not really what I am worried about, s. above. Furthermore the usage of `loop` itself is fine for me, because I *like* its DSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LOOP syntax violation**

There is a `LOOP` syntax violation: your `LOOP` starts with a `WHILE` clause and `FOR` clauses follow. This is not allowed according to the ANSI CL LOOP syntax. `WHILE` is a *main clause*, which follow **after** the *variable clauses*.

**WHILE is not needed**

The `while...for...` is just a `for`.

**LOOP iterations in the sub-LOOPs are creating side-effects**

I would propose to rewrite the sub-LOOPS to return values. That would make it easier to refactor them into functions.

**My version of your code**

I tried to keep the main loop small and remove the side-effects.
If the function calls are too much overhead, we could let Lisp inline them with a `INLINE` declaration.

Each of the sub-functions have a purpose and can be described and tested separately.

```
(defun lexicographic-permutation% (order n &aux (len (1+ order)))
  "Returns the Nth permutation of integers from 0 upto order."
  (labels ((iota (n)
             (loop :for i :upto n :collect i))
           (compute-i (permutation order)
             (loop :for i :downfrom order
                   :when (< (aref permutation (1- i))
                            (aref permutation i))
                   :do (return i)))
           (compute-j (permutation len i)
             (loop :for j :downfrom len
                   :when (> (aref permutation (1- j))
                            (aref permutation (1- i)))
                   :do (return j)))
           (swap-ij (permutation i j)
             (rotatef (aref permutation i) (aref permutation j)))
           (swap (permutation i j)
             (loop :for i1 :from i :and j1 :downfrom j
                   :while (< i1 j1)
                   :do (swap-ij permutation (1- i1) (1- j1)))))
    (let ((permutation (make-array len :initial-contents (iota order))))
      (loop :for count :from 1 :upto n
            :for i = (compute-i permutation order)
            :for j = (compute-j permutation len i)
            :do
            (swap-ij permutation (1- i) (1- j))
            (swap    permutation (1+ i) len))
      permutation)))
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for and very inspiring! I guess you have chosen `labels` because of the recursive call of `swap-ij` in `swap`. Is it considered to be bad style to have an `flet` and `labels` block within the same function?

Comment: @MartinBuchmann: yes, the functions might be used in other local functions. One could use an FLET and a LABELs part, but the advantage in intent over code complexity is not huge.